# How to unfold a Coq Fixpoint literally

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I was trying to unfold a `Fixpoint` definition and obtain the body of the definition. But Coq wouldn't give the body of the definition literally. Instead, it's giving me something starting with `(fix ...)`, which I cannot make use of.

For example, in proving the following from [Coq.Init.Wf](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html)

```
Lemma Fix_F_eq :
  forall (x:A) (r:Acc x),
  F x (fun (y:A) (p:R y x) => Fix_F y (Acc_inv x r y p)) = Fix_F x r.
  Proof. intros.
```

The state is:

```
...
______________________________________(1/1)
F x
  (fun (y : A) (p : R y x) =>
   Fix_F y (Acc_inv x r y p)) = 
Fix_F x r
```

Now, `Fix_F` on the RHS was defined exactly the same as the LHS:

```
Fixpoint Fix_F (x:A) (r:Acc x) {struct r} : P x :=
  F x (fun (y:A) (p:R y x) => Fix_F y (Acc_inv x r y p)).
```

I tried to make it a `trivial` equality by:

```
unfold Fix_F at 2.
```

Yet, I got something like `(fix Fix_F ... )` on the RHS, and I can't proceed along this line any further:

```
______________________________________(1/1)
F x
  (fun (y : A) (p : R y x) =>
   Fix_F y (Acc_inv x r y p)) =
(fix
 Fix_F (x0 : A) (r0 : Acc x0) {struct r0} :
   P x0 :=
   F x0
     (fun (y : A) (p : R y x0) =>
      Fix_F y (Acc_inv x0 r0 y p))) x r
```

The question is:

**Is there a way to unfold the above `Fixpoint` to its function body to the letter?**

Note: I know there is a workaround to prove this example.

```
Proof. intros. destruct r. simpl. trivial. 
  Defined.
```

But I am more interested in the `unfold`-ing approach if it is valid.

Comment: Can you write your expected goal explicitly?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, since it's not a `Definition` but a `Fixpoint` so the definition is what you get in the `unfold`. I'm not a COQ expert though.

Comment: @Elazar, the body of the Fixpoint definition is: `F x (fun (y:A) (p:R y x) => Fix_F y (Acc_inv x r y p))`. I was expecting to get this via unfold, then what's to be proved is a reflexivity. Could you explain the difference between a `Definition` and `Fixpoint` that you mentioned and why it's impossible to expand the Fixpoint definition as-is?

Comment: As far as I understand, `Fixpoint` is syntactic sugar for a call to a function `fix` (intrinsic to COQ, I guess) that is the [Fixed-point Combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). The actual definition is exactly what you see after `unfold`. Expanding the fixpoint definiton as is means you remove the syntactic sugar and left with a different definition.

Comment: In other words, these definitions are not identical by definition, so your strategy cannot possibly work.
Again, everything based on my shallow understanding of the logic and system.

Comment: The comments of @Elazar are correct. Rather than unfolding the definition, what you really want here is to do one step of computation. To do that try `cbv`.